# android Create a button with something above it

Tags: android, button

I wanna create a button class which extends Button.And when I click my custom button ,it will show a circle shape above it and then the circle shape dispears.The code likes:
public class MyButton extends Button {

```
public GlowButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public GlowButton(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    //Add the code for show the shape
    return super.performClick();
}
```

}
Is this possible ? And How can i create the shape above the button?
thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why not just use a nine patch graphic and toggle button?

Comment: @trgraglia thanks,can you explain in detail?the shape is larger than the button

Comment: are you familiar with 9 patch graphics? http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: Also, is this just one button or in a list or something? if it is one button, i would go with the first answer below of just changing visibility on a circle image. if you are looking for an animation, look into animations. Quick action menus are a good way to get a glimpse of that quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you can do is load an image from a drawable, where your shape has already been created. Put the shape above the button in the layout (XML) file using an imageview, and then change the visibility of that imageview to invisible on default. When the button is clicked, change the visibility to visible.

Comment: yeah I have thought about this method before,but I wonder if there are other maybe better ways

Comment: I can't think of any. If you wrote a custom class that used both an image view and a button like mentioned above, it would be easier for repetitive uses.